# PorcupineInvalidArgumentError: Initialization failed: [0] Keyword file (.ppn) file has incorrect format or belongs to a different platform

Tags: reactjs, typescript, speech-recognition

Here is my code

```
import model from './lib/model_file.js'
import keyword from './lib/hello-ravi_en_wasm_v3_0_0/keyword_file.js'

console.log(model);
console.log(keyword);
const porcupineKeyword = {
  // publicPath: "./lib/hello-ravi_en_wasm_v3_0_0/alexa_wasm.ppn",
  base64: keyword,
  label: "alexa"
}

const porcupineModel = {
  // publicPath: "./lib/porcupine_params.pv",
  base64: model
}

...

const initEngine = useCallback(async () => {
    console.log(BuiltInKeyword);
    await init(
      "jPTQx+....",
      [porcupineKeyword],
      porcupineModel
    );
  }, [])
```

Here is my react package:

```
"@picovoice/porcupine-react": "^3.0.3",
"@picovoice/web-voice-processor": "^4.0.8",
```

I am getting this error

```
PorcupineInvalidArgumentError: Initialization failed: [0] Keyword file (.ppn) file has incorrect format or belongs to a different platform. [1] Picovoice Error (code 00000136) [2] Loading keyword file at alexafailed withINVALID_ARGUMENT.
```

Wasted a whole day to get the demo up and running but i am unable to. Any help would be awesome.

Steps To Reproduce
Download the react demo folder
train a wake word on console
run the demo with the files and api keys
Expected Behavior
The demo should have run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your import paths are correct. (The files you are importing should have .ppn (for keyword) and .pv (for model) extensions not .js)
If it's a custom word make sure you selected right platform while creating the .ppv file. (for react it would be web)